# Node: Confusing behaviour related to saving a TypeORM model using await inside a callback / promises clearing

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, async-await

I'm making a system that loops over all my emails (from a maildir folder), and I'm using an old NPM package called `eml-format` to parse each maildir file (single emails).  The `eml-format` package doesn't use promises, it just takes a callback to execute after reading the email file, and inside that callback I'm trying to save the email's metadata to Postgres using `await` with TypeORM.  Here's the relevant part of the code I'm having issues with (the code looks a bit pointless as I've removed everything irrelevant to the actual main problem).

The Maildir() class is my TypeORM model (which refers to a postgres table called `maildir`).

This snippet of code is looped for every email:

```
/* *****************************
 * START OF TOGGLEBLOCK
const md1 = new Maildir();
md1.folder = 'md1';
await db.entityManager.save(md1);
 * END OF TOGGLEBLOCK
***************************** */


emlformat.read(eml, { headersOnly: false }, async (error, data) => {

    console.log('before save');
    const md2 = new Maildir();
    md2.folder = 'md2';
    await db.entityManager.save(md2);
    console.log('after save');

});
```

When running with the code as-is above (with TOGGLEBLOCK disabled):

- "before save" is repeatedly printed to the console
- `await db.entityManager.save(md2);` does not wait, they seem to just queue up all at once (no good when I run on my entire email account of about 50,000 emails)
- after they're all queued up, they all save to the database
- then all the "after save" messages get printed to the console at the same time

If I simply enable the TOGGLEBLOCK code, then the md2 await in the callback works exactly as I expect it to, for each email it does these in order:

- shows one "before save" message
- saves the md2 record to the database - await waits as expected
- shows one "after save" message
- ...then does the same again for each email

The TOGGLEBLOCK/md1 code isn't needed, it's just some junk I put in there while trying to figure this all out it.  Why does having this extra code outside the callback change whether or not the md2 await works inside the callback?

I'm guessing it's something to do with with the TOGGLEBLOCK clearing out the promises or something?

I just want to delete the junk TOGGLEBLOCK/md1 code entirely.  How can I get the md2 await to work without it?

If you've got a suggestion you're not entirely sure of, please just post it as an answer rather than a comment directly under the question (gets too confusing with multiple conversations interlaced together).

Comment: Is this code inside a loop?  Please show a wider code context.  I'm thinking that the toggle block is "pausing" your loop which helps you get the desired sequence, but when it's not there, nothing pauses the loop because the `await` in your callback does not affect the loop.  If that's the case, the solution is to promisify `emlformat.read()` and `await` it in your loop.

Comment: Where'd you go?   I asked some clarifying questions and you're not around to answer.  My window to help closes in a few minutes.  Now, it appears I've wasted my time and you don't get an answer yet.  It appears you've been around here long enough to know that after posting, you should check back several times within the first 30 minutes to see if people understood your question or if you have to clarify things.  That's your best chance to get quick help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond @jfriend00 ... had been a long & frustrating day, and it was about 3am here so I posted this and went to bed hoping that my misuse/misunderstanding of combined callbacks/async would be obvious to someone.  The answer from `m1ch4ls` was exactly what I needed.  

I spent about an hour or more writing the question and modifying the code to remove irrelevant stuff to try to make it easier for people to read more quickly, but maybe went too far in this case.  I'll use your suggestion next time to stick around for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap `emlformat.read` with Promise and then it would play well with `async/await`

```
const readEmlFormat = eml => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => emlformat.read(eml, { headersOnly: false }, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(data);
    }

  }));

const data = await readEmlFormat(eml);
console.log('before save');
const md2 = new Maildir();
md2.folder = 'md2';
await db.entityManager.save(md2);
console.log('after save');
```

Note that the issue was that **you've used async function as a callback which was not awaited anywhere**!

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  I'm still getting my ahead around promises/await etc... I seem to understand what most of the guides are explaining in isolation, but still struggling a bit putting the pieces together in the right order/way.  You've really helped me, cheers!